# Two hibernate validators on one field. Need to choose only one

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have a class:

```
public class Foo {
    @Length(min = 6, max = 30)
    @Pattern(regexp = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*)", message = "{error.password.too_simple}")
    private String password;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

As you see, there is one field 'password' and two validate annotations. But, in some situations, I want that only one should be applied, not both.
For example: if I have empty string: "" I want, that only one restriction be applied: the first (*@Length*), but in my situation applied both restrictions.
What should I do, how can I applied only one restriction in the situation?

Comment: If you were familiar with custom validation with HibernateValidator then you could customize validation as per your requirements something like [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-validator). **It's just as an example**. It could take some time, if you're going to do it first time. You also need to learn validation group as and when required (and it must require, if you customize validation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign the constraints to different [validation groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) and validate them using a group sequence, e.g. by re-defining the [default group sequence](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-default-group-class) for `Foo`:

```
public interface EmptyChecks {}

@GroupSequence( { EmptyChecks.class, Foo.class } )
public class Foo {
    @Length(min = 6, max = 30, groups=EmptyChecks.class)
    @Pattern(regexp = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*)", message = "{error.password.too_simple}")
    private String password;

    //...
}
```

Now the `@Pattern` constraint will only be validated if the `@Length` constraint is valid.

Your specific case might also be solved by accepting an empty value (`^$`) in the regular expression of the `@Password` constraint:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "(^$|(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*)", message = "")
```

That way both constraints will be validated but only the `@Length` constraint will fail for an emtpy input value.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! But, what if I want to restrict not empty String. I want to apply the reg exp to any word with length from 6 to 30. In other cases should be applied *@Length* restriction?